# Android sync strings.xml

Tags: android, internationalization, translation, synchronization

How can I sync my strings.xml in Android if I'm using localisation and a new string needs also to be translated in values-de/strings.xml, values-ru/strings.xml ... 
Do I really have to copy paste it in everey file - or is there a tool for managing translations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't provide a translation, the default value will be found in values/strings.xml if that file exists.  MOTODEV Studio has a localization editor that allows you to see all your strings in a spreadsheet configuration, which might be easier for you to visualize.  If you don't want to install MOTODEV Studio, you can install the Sequoyah plugins into your Eclipse IDE and get most of the functionality.

http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/

http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/

[image: MOTODEV Studio Localization editor]

UPDATE 2014/08/08 - The former MOTODEV plugins that were submitted to AOSP are finding new life in a Github project called [Proteus](https://github.com/kingargyle/proteus).  The string editor is included in Proteus and can be used as-is.  The automatic translation feature through Google Translate doesn't work, but the column editor does work.

Comment: Thank you, for something linke this I  have been looking for.

Comment: @Sebastien - The Sequoyah project has not been active since August 2012. [Here is the email](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/sequoyah-dev/msg00426.html) announcing the ramp-down. There was some sorting out of the sub-projects at Eclipse Foundation because the mobile Java stuff was still active. Perhaps it finally happened. For what it's worth, it was a fun project. Several of the team members wanted to contribute individually, but that's not allowed under the bylaws without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your pain. Here is what I do. A java program parses string.xml. It creates a string-de.csv. I put that file in docs.google.com to share. I use the google translate function to populate the auto-translated column. I found some good hearted users to help me fix those translation. I save the translated google doc and create values-de/string.xml out of it using the same Java program.